Python Pip error- ERROR: Invalid requirement: '#'
I am trying to install a package and pip throws an error:
ERROR: Invalid requirement: '#' 

I have tried reinstalling pip, updating it and downgrading it. Nothing works.
Note: I am doing this on jupyter notebook

Turns out I was installing the library like this-
!pip install pandas #If not already installed
Removing the commented part helped. The error arose due to the hashtag symbol where the comment starts.

Hmmm. The thing with comments is probably OS specific. It is fine on Linux. TIP: You should update to current best practices and use %pip install when installing inside an active Jupyter .ipynb file. The magic pip command variation was added in 2019 to insure the install occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that backs the active notebook.  The exclamation point doesn't do that and can lead to issues. See more about the modern %pip install command here. ...

 The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues.
